# Create menu using images using css in html

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm new in HTML and CSS.
Want to create menu with image and also want to show menu separator, menu should be horizontally aligned.
when we hover mouse on menu item, image and text color should change.
It should be look like as per image.
[image]

sry I forgot to upload the code, uploading here.
but now I want to show some menu items on left side( left align) and others on right side( right align)

```
.mainmenu{
  background-color: black;
}
.mainmenu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }

.mainmenu li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: gray;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: black 0 1px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-right: 1px solid #030304;
  border-left: 1px solid #36393C;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.mainmenu ul.menu {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainmenu ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 16.666666666666668%;
}

.mainmenu ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #76b900;
}    

img {
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}

<div>
   <div class="mainmenu ">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/home.png">HOME</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/users.png">
            USERS
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/gallary.png">
            GALLARY
           <a/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/community.png">
            COMMUNITY
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your code so far? can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Rajesh. Please provide a maximum of informations and precisions to specific programming issues. Please provide your work. What are your difficulties exactly ?

Comment: Also review [ask] questions on SO

Comment: sry, I forgot to upload the code, uploaded the same.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.menu li {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
}
ul.menu li a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 60px;
  /* To sift text off the background-image */
  color: #3E789F;
  background: url("../images/mySprite.png") no-repeat;
  /* As all link share the same background-image */
}
ul.menu li.firefox a {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
ul.menu li.chrome a {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
}
ul.menu li.ie a {
  background-position: 0 -200px;
}
ul.menu li.safari a {
  background-position: 0 -300px;
}
ul.menu li.opera a {
  background-position: 0 -400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="firefox"><a href="#">Firefox</a>
  </li>
  <li class="chrome"><a href="#">Chrome</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ie"><a href="#">Explorer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="opera"><a href="#">Opera</a>
  </li>
  <li class="safari"><a href="#">Safari</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: also use this tutorial http://studentwebhosting.com/tutorials/css-based-menu-with-images/

Comment: Please explain your code - in its current state, this is a low quality answer.